# Looking for a good JQuery counter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, plugins

I have a website that has members. I want to create a feature that is a real time (with out page load ) counter of how many members are signed in. I have the signed in user in a variable so I'm looking for someway to incorporate it using that. Anyone know of a good plug-in or Jquery script to do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really don't need a plugin so much, just create a page that does nothing but echo the count then call that page on an interval, for example:

```
function updateCount() {
  $('#userCount').load('myCounter.php', function() {
     setTimeout(updateCount, 2000);
  });
}
$(updateCount); //run on document.ready
```

This uses [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to fetch the count and place it in the `#userCount` element (a `<span>` or `<div>`, whatever it is), wait 2 seconds and do it again.  You want to avoid [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) in these cases because the ajax request time is an unknown, and you don't want those to start overlapping.  Instead, use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) so it runs again 2 seconds (or however often you want) *after* the request completes.

Answer (score 0):

[Full code](http://www.crackerworld.in/2013/12/page-counter-in-php-j-query.html)

```
<?php
$count_my_page = ("hitcounter.txt");
$hits = file($count_my_page);
$hits[0] ++;
$fp = fopen($count_my_page , "w");
fputs($fp , "$hits[0]");
fclose($fp);
$hits[0];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var intcnt = <?php echo $hits[0];?>;
//document.write(intcnt);
var myCounter = new flipCounter('fct', {value:intcnt, inc:123, pace:600, auto:false});
</script>
```